# Error passing multiple inputs into Keras model

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, classification

I want to train a binary classifier using Keras and my training data is of shape `(2000,2,128)` and labels of shape `(2000,)` as Numpy arrays.

The idea is to train such that embeddings together in a single array means they are either same or different, labelled using 0 or 1 respectively.

The training data looks like:
`[[[0 1 2 ....128][129.....256]][[1 2 3 ...128][9 9 3 5...]].....]`
 and the labels looks like `[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0..]`.

Here is the code:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

from keras.models import Model

frst_input = Input(shape=(128,), name='frst_input')
scnd_input = Input(shape=(128,),name='scnd_input')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([frst_input, scnd_input])
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x=(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))(x)
model=Model(inputs=[frst_input, scnd_input], outputs=[x])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',
              loss_weights=[ 0.2],metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am getting the following error while running this code:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[ 0.07124118, -0.02316936, -0.12737238, ...,  0.15822273,
      0.00129827, -0.02457245],
    [ 0.15869428, -0.0570458 , -0.10459555, ...,  0.0968155 ,
      0.0183982 , -0.077924...
```

How can I resolve this issue? Is my code correct to train the classifier using two inputs to classify?

Comment: Pass a **list** of two arrays corresponding to two input layers when calling `fit` method.

Comment: Don't use `softmax` as the activation of last layer. Otherwise, since it has one unit, it would always output 1. Instead use `sigmoid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have two options here:

1) Reshape the training data to `(2000, 128*2)` and define only one input layer:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 128*2)

inp = Input(shape=(128*2,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inp)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))(x)
model=Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[x])
```

2) Define two input layers, as you have already done, and pass a **list** of two input arrays when calling `fit` method:

```
# assuming X_train have a shape of `(2000, 2, 128)` as you suggested
model.fit([X_train[:,0], X_train[:,1]], y_train, ...)
```

Further, since you are doing binary classification here, you need to use `sigmoid` as the activation of last layer (i.e. using `softmax` in this case would always outputs 1, since `softmax` normalizes the outputs such that their sum equals to one).